# Connect to session DBus on different computer

Tags: c++, qt, dbus, qtdbus

I can run my Qt DBus test by connecting to the session bus:

```
QDBusConnection connection = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
connection.registerService(...)
....
TestserviceInterface testserviceInterface( .... , connection, &a);
```

But can I connect to this DBus from a different computer. I know I can do something like this:

```
 connection = QDBusConnection::connectToPeer("tcp:host=127.0.0.1,port=45000", Testservice::ServiceName);
```

But how would I obtain the port? Whatever I have tried, there seems to be no connection. Or am I at the wrong path here and need to us Peer 2 Peer DBus instead of the session bus?

I am almost sure the service name is correct, as I can see it `qdbusviewer`. When I use `dbus-monitor` the output does not mean a lot to me, I cannot see any port, etc.

**Any idea how I would be able to connect from another computer?**

PS: I am aware that there is something like gabriel for tunnelling via SSH (http://gabriel.sourceforge.net/howto.html). This is **not** what I am up to, I am looking for a "direct connection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session bus daemon usually listens unix socket `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket` ( check your `/usr/local/etc/dbus-1/session.conf` config ) which means that you can't access it remotely via tcp. Start some kind of port forwarding on computer where bus daemon is running (using `socat` for example) or configure it to listen tcp.

Comment: So it means, I can connect the session bus via TCP if it is configured to listen to tcp. Need to try.

Comment: I suggest to launch simple service which listens tcp and connects to system bus instead of reconfiguring dbus daemon

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH to create a tunnel for DBus.

```
ssh -nNT -L ./dbus_on_local:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket user@remote
```

[Explanation](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+-nNT+-L+./dbus_on_local%3A%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdbus%2Fsystem_bus_socket+user%40remote)

This will create a local "file" (unix domain socket) `dbus_on_local` that you can connect to.