# Connect to DBus service via TCP

Tags: c++, qt, dbus

I'm new in work with interprocess communication. I need you help and clear explanation. I have 2 applications. One of them is a service and one is a client. I've used QT/C++ to write them. When they are working on the one local PC - all is good. But I need to separate them.

So, I have a service on the PC with IP 192.30.82.101.
I connect it to bus using next code:

```
QDBusConnection connection = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
connection.registerObject("/my/service/MyService", mySvc);
connection.registerService("my.service.MyService");
```

Also I have a client on the another PC with IP 192.30.82.40. 
I connect my client using the next code:

```
QDBusServiceWatcher serviceWatcher = new QDBusServiceWatcher(); 
serviceWatcher->setConnection(QDBusConnection::sessionBus());
serviceWatcher->addWatchedService("my.service.MyService");
```

.....

```
    myServiceProxy = new local::MyService("my.service.MyService", 
                   "/my/service/MyService", QDBusConnection::sessionBus(), this);
```

I need to connect my client on the PC with IP 192.30.82.40 to the service on the PC 192.30.82.101. I don't know how to do this. I've found a few topics on the forum but I still don't understand what to do.

So, what I have found:

1. On the PC where is my service I have to add additional lines to /etc/dbus-1/session.conf:

`<listen>tcp:host=<host>,port=<port></listen>`

`<listen>unix:tmpdir=/tmp</listen>`

`<auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>`

`<allow_anonymous/>`

Here I have a question: Which IP address I have to use here (server or client)? Which port is used for DBUS (is it default port or how I can check it)? I have tried to set an IP address of my client PC, my service PC and different ports, and port 0, but I've got an error:  Failed to bind socket "172.30.82.40:0": Cannot assign requested address.

2. On the client side I have to set DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS with the same address: `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=<host>,port=<port>`.

I've tried to do this with different ports, with 0 port, because this means - use any free port. But I cannot start bus daemon with any port+IP configuration.

Also I've tried to connect client QDBusServiceWatcher to bus using the next code:

```
serviceWatcher->setConnection(QDBusConnection::connectToBus("tcp:host=<host>,port=<port>", "session"));
```

It was not successful. 
I have no idea how to connect them to each other.
Can anybody, please, explain me how it should be, how does it work?
I want to clearly understanding how does it work?

I will be very grateful for any help. I hope for your kindness.

> **UPDATE**
>   I have found how to connect my client to DBus bus via TCP:

1. On the PC where is my service I have to add additional lines to /etc/dbus-1/session.conf:

`<listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=6667,family=ipv4</listen>`

`<listen>unix:tmpdir=/tmp</listen>`

`<auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>`

`<allow_anonymous/>`

Here we should add PORT. We can find it in dbus config file.

2. On the client side I have to set DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS with corresponding address (IP of PC where is service): 
   `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=192.50.88.10,port=6667,family=ipv4`.

Thats all. We can check it just started dbus-monitor.

> But now I have another issue: **how to connect my client to my service?**
>   I need to do something more to connect to my service.
>   I guess that this is something like:

```
QDBusConnection::connectToBus("tcp:host=<host>,port=<port>","connectionName");
```

I've tried to connect with any random name, but this is not correct.
So, my question is - **where I can get correct connection name?**

Comment: Hi Елена)))  [D-Bus Chat Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-chat-example.html)

Comment: or [QtDbus](https://habrahabr.ru/post/185212/)  project ping pong)

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot find here anything about TCP DBus communication. Here client and service are working on the same PC, and, sure, registered on the one bus session.

Comment: [Please read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus#Internals)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Correct answer to my question is:**

1. On the PC where is one application add additional lines to 
   /etc/dbus-1/session.conf:
   `<listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=6667,family=ipv4</listen>`

   `<listen>unix:tmpdir=/tmp</listen>`

   `<auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>`

   `<allow_anonymous/>`

   Correct port you can find in dbus config file.
2. On the client side It's needed to set DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS with
   corresponding address (IP of PC where is service):
   `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=192.50.88.10,port=6667,family=ipv4`.
3. To connect to session where is alive your remote app use the next
   connection string:

   ```
   DBusConnection::connectToBus("tcp:host=192.50.88.10,port=6667", "qt_default_session_bus"));
   ```

   How to know session name? I've added log in my service:

   ```
   qDebug() << "Connection name: " << connection.name();
   ```

   Then started app, copy printed name and set it in my client.

Now it works!

Comment: [Intercomunicate processes in different(remote) machines through DBus](http://gabriel.sourceforge.net/howto.html)

Comment: [Connect to session DBus on different computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137703/connect-to-session-dbus-on-different-computer)