# DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected. DBUS over TCP

Tags: python, linux, tcp, dbus

With the help of the following Stackoverflow answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275973/1277793) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45487266/1277793) I was able to successfully connect to the system DBUS remotely over TCP/IP. 
And using [D-FEET](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DFeet) I'm able to verify the connection.
[image]

As can be seen by the above screenshot, i'm able to access the remote bus, and i'm able to successfully call the **org.freedesktop.hostname1** object and its interfaces.

But while attemtping to access the **com.aldogroup.Calculator**, I get the following exception thrown
[image]

This **AccessDenied** also occurs when accessing other services such as the org.bluez (I haven't been able to find a pattern)

**UPDATE**

My system.conf file

```
<busconfig>                                                                     
        <listen>tcp:host=0.0.0.0,port=55557,family=ipv4</listen>                
        <listen>unix:tmpdir=/tmp</listen>                       

        <auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>                                  
        <allow_anonymous/>               
        <apparmor mode="disabled"/>
        <policy user="root">       
                <allow own="com.aldogroup.Calculator"/>
                <allow send_destination="com.aldogroup.Calculator"/>
                <allow send_interface="com.aldogroup.Calculator"/>  
                <allow send_type="method_call"/>                    
        </policy>                                                   
</busconfig>
```

DBUS busctl output

```
root@aldogroup-dart-6ul-1b6be6:~# busctl introspect com.aldogroup.Calculator /com/aldogroup/Calculator
NAME                                TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE FLAGS
com.aldogroup.Calculator            interface -         -            -
.Divide                             method    xx        x            -
.Multiply                           method    xx        x            -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable interface -         -            -
.Introspect                         method    -         s            -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer           interface -         -            -
.GetMachineId                       method    -         s            -
.Ping                               method    -         -            -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties     interface -         -            -
.Get                                method    ss        v            -
.GetAll                             method    s         a{sv}        -
.Set                                method    ssv       -            -
.PropertiesChanged                  signal    sa{sv}as  -            -
```

Best regards,

Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by creation a .conf file in /etc/dbus-1/system.d/

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
    <policy user="root">
        <allow own="com.aldogroup.Calculator"/>
        <allow send_destination="com.aldogroup.Calculator"/>
        <allow send_interface="com.aldogroup.Calculator.Divide"/>
        <allow send_interface="com.aldogroup.Calculator.Multiply"/>
    </policy>
    <policy at_console="true">
        <allow send_destination="com.aldogroup.Calculator"/>
    </policy>
    <policy context="default">
        <allow send_destination="com.aldogroup.Calculator"/>
    </policy>
</busconfig>
```

Not sure why the policies specified in system.conf didn't do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in the accepted answer didn't quite work for me. Instead, I used the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
   <policy user="pi">
      <allow eavesdrop="true" />
      <allow eavesdrop="true" send_destination="*" />
      <allow own="com.example.calculator" />
   </policy>
</busconfig>
```

After this is done, run:

```
sudo systemctl restart dbus
```